# What default theme does Chrome use on Linux?

Tags: google-chrome, 20.10

Can anyone please let me know what the theme is called that Chrome uses by default?

[image]

Comment: Any question should always include the version of Ubuntu you are using. Please edit the question or add a flag. What version is it?

Comment: Sorry, it's 20.10!

Comment: Can you explain your question a little-bit? @orschiro

Comment: I am just curious to know the name of the theme because I really like it!